# Hiding a Button from Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am using a VF page for my 'Visualforce Tabs' Community Home page. I have a custom button on top of it which says: **Instructions Reviewed**. Clicking on it would take them to another page. And whenever the user logins again, the button should not be shown at all. How can I achieve this via code?

I think a checkbox on the User record can be used as a flag. As I am an administrator and very new to programming, I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to update a checkbox value whenever a user clicks on the button and based on that checkbox value, if you want to hide the button, this might work well:

Visualforce:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!updateFlag}" 
           rendered="{!NOT(instructionsFlag)}" 
           value="Instructions Reviewed" />
```

Apex class:

```
public Boolean instructionsFlag {get; set;}
public User currentUser = [SELECT Checkbox__c FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

public EducationPageController(){
    instructionsFlag = currentUser.Checkbox__c;
}

public void updateFlag(){
    if(!instructionsFlag){
        currentUser.Checkbox__c = TRUE;
        update currentUser;
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh, missed that user thing, kind of looks like my answer, but you fulfilled it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the rendered attribute on your button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!foo}" value="Review" rendered="{!NOT(reviewed)}"/>
```

Your Controller would need to define the variable reviewed:

```
Boolean reviewed{ get; set; }

// Constructor
public PageController() {
    reviewed = [SELECT Reviewed__c FROM YourObject__c WHERE Id = whatever].Reviewed__c;
}
```

I have no input about your controller's context so this is a more generic answer.